# Craft CMS SSL Issues

Tags: ssl, craftcms

I'm having issues forcing an SSL on my website. I think the issue may be that my root folder is my 'web' folder.

I've searched online and tried a few variations of htaccess but none of them seem to work.

Here is the latest I've tried:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # Send would-be 404 requests to Craft
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(favicon\.ico|apple-touch-icon.*\.png)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule (.+) index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

My domain points to my web folder and my htaccess belongs in the web folder.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

When you accept traffic on port 80 and port 443 and use Apache, you usually have 2 virtual host configurations: one for each port. A simple approach would therefore be to simply redirect any incoming port 80 requests to the SSL/TLS-enabled URL:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    RedirectMatch permanent (.*) https://example.com$1
</VirtualHost>
```

If you want to handle several hostnames, `mod_rewrite` might come in handy (to my knowledge, `RedirectMatch` does not support variables such as `%{HTTP_HOST}`), but if not, that’s it.